# FromBody Item Coming Back as Null

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using JSGrid to allow me to modify data. I am trying to setup the updateItem as follows:

```
updateItem: function (item) {
                return $.ajax({
                    type: "PUT",
                    url: "/api/data/" + item.logID,
                    data: item,
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json"
                });
            }
```

I have a model as follows:

```
public class LogEntry
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public bool modified { get; set; }
    public DateTime inTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime outTime { get; set; }
    public double totalHrs { get; set; }
    public int logID { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my ApiController Class that contains the Put method:

```
public class DataController : ApiController
{
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]LogEntry item)
    {
        if(item != null)
        {
           //DO STUFF
        }

    }
}
```

However no matter what I do the item is always Null. I have tried the following:

- Change to [FromBody]JObject item
- Change to [FromBody]String item
- Change the data: field to Json.Stringify
- Change to [FromBody]String to just String
- Add and remove context type of application/json;charset=utf-8 to the updateItem ajax call.

I have used Fiddler to see the data sent back. It shows the correct JSON being sent but the Put method doesn't seem to be getting that data.

Any ideas on what might be causing this behavior would be great. I have been researching around but nothing has worked yet.

**Resolution Notes**

It turned out that both answers from Caz1224 and CodeFuller aided in fixing this. CodeFuller's way of finding the error message lead me to the JSON coming back to the server. It was messed up even though Fiddler said it was correct. I changed my Ajax call to stringify the item. Which then matched my Model exactly.

```
return $.ajax({
                    type: "PUT",
                    url: "/api/data/" + item.logID,
                    data: JSON.stringify(item),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json"
```

Comment: How is "item" getting built? is it a proper JSON string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FromBody` attribute is not strictly required here because non-simple types are built by the default from the request body.

I don't see any problems with your code so far, it should work for valid request. Seems like the problem is with the request sent and it causes model binding error. To proceed with the analysis check the following:

1. Check the value of `ActionContext.ModelState.IsValid` in `Put()` method. Is it true or false?
2. If it's `false`, check collection `ActionContext.ModelState.Values` in debugger. It should contain model binding errors that will hint you were the problem actually happens.

Comment: Alright that did show something I can use to try to fix the issue. I am getting an Error parsing boolean value. I will play with this for a bit and try to see if I can get this figured out. When I take a look at the JSON tab in Fiddler it simple has JSON=firstName and that's it. So I am guessing it's something there.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was able to successfully get code to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and its painful!!

This is what ended up working for me.
The first part is my javascript (I guess that is how you are making your JSON)

"List" is my array that PERFECTLY matches (Even to the case, it matters) to my C# model.

**Javascript Build List**

```
var List = [];
$.each(_questions, function () {
    var limitID = this.id.substr(-1);
    var Quest = $('#Quest_' + ID).val();
    var objectpush = {
        LimitID: limitID,
        Quest: Quest,
        ID: ID
    }
    List.push(objectpush);
```

Then in the AJAX call further on I specify data like so:

```
data: JSON.stringify(List),
```

And finally this is on my C# API

```
public JsonResult QueryLimits(int UserID, [FromBody] List<List> List)
```

Hope this helps get you on the track. Don't just copy the code as I changed the name to List throughout my code and that will cause issues!

Caz

Comment: You can use `[JsonProperty]` to map your class properties to the JSON properties, if they do not match, including casing.

Comment: Thanks Frank I will look into that for future coding. I am just pedantic about case =P

Comment: Looking back at the JSON via Fiddler it appears to match exactly. However I changed my code since then and now it appears to be a bit messed up. Using CodeFuller's method to see the error message showed that I am getting Error Parsing Boolean Value.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It ended up being some bad JSON even though Fiddler said it was correct.